# Get message from Notification and display on the app

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to develop push notification service using GCM. I am able to receive notification send from the server onto my device. On clicking the notification the app opens. Good. Now what i want is that the message which is there on the notification should also be displayed on the app. How can i do this?

```
Code in GCMintentservice.java:
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search_)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Now i am getting the notification but on clicking the notification i go the app but the message is not there. What should i do. I have a text view in the main app. How can i update that text view with the message from the notification? Something maybe to do on OnCreate in the main app? Please Help.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should supply a Bundle containing the details of the GCM into the PendingIntent's wrapped Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
intent.putExtra(...);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: how should I get the value in MainActivity class?

Comment: @Saty It appears you're missing some basics. I'd suggest reading up on [what Intents are](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), then following up with [this information about Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Comment: I tried all intent things however I think the two flags which are set ( notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)) is creating the issue for which on MainActivity onCreate is not called, if onCreate is not called then how would I be able to grab intent's value.

Comment: shall I put values on normal intent or pending intent? please suggest.

Comment: The flags you've provided are Intent flags, and should be set on the Intent; [see the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29). `onCreate()` isn't being invoked because the activity was already created and was still running. You can instead observe `onNewIntent()`, as [described in the documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks).

Comment: okay thanx for this light. so you are saying I shall continue using those flags but instead of retrieving values in onCreate I will try to recover the values in onNewIntent of Activity. 
is it correct?

Comment: I have no idea what your use case is, so I can't encourage you to do one thing or another. However, provided those flags *and that your activity is already running*, your intent will arrive in `onNewIntent()`. If your activity is not running, you may still expect the intent to arrive in `onCreate()`.

Comment: okay you can suggest me...I will not blame you if ur suggestion does not work. I wanted to say if I will set a value in intent of Pending intent (as shown in the question code) and set the notification. If I want to retrieve that value then can I use onNewIntent in MainActivity.class if onCreate is getting called.

Comment: @Saty That will work, but I would suggest placing your business logic for handling taps from notifications in `onNewIntent()`, and calling `onNewIntent()` directly from `onCreate()` to ensure that the same behavior happens whether or not the activity was already running.

Comment: I tried setting the value with putExtra("message", message) and onNewIntent tried with getStringExtra("message") with no result and more over onNewIntent is also not getting called. Please suggest if you have anything else in mind, I am following androidhive's GCM tutorial- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question so you can provide some code and get help from others. Feel free to drop a link to the question here and I'll take a look.